# Probability Question with k branches

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Suppose my knowledge/ignorance of the number of branches of a certain store is given by the following probability law:

P(k branches) = (1 − p)p^k where 0 < p < 1 and k = 0, 1, 2, 3, . . .

If I subsequently discover that they have at least 7 branches (e.g. I walk into a store and it says “branch #7”) what new probability law describes my revised knowledge.

I was told that the answer is p^7 but I don't understand how to get to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be number of branches. We need to find $P(X=k|X\geq 7)=\frac{P({X=k}\ \cap\  {X\geq 7})}{P(X\geq7)}$. The numerator is $0$ unless $k\geq 7$, and equals to the old distribution, $(1-p)p^k$ when it is. $P(X\geq 7)=(1-p)\sum_{k=7}^{\infty}{p^k}=p^7$. So, your updated distribution will be $(1-p)p^{k-7}$, $k\geq 7$.

The $p^7$ you're told is just $P(X\geq 7)$, it cannot be your updated distribution since it doesn't depend on $k$.

Comment: I understand how p^7 is found. how did you get p^(k-7) from that?

Comment: Divide your old distribution by it